# How can I preserve sessions when I deploy to Heroku?

Tags: php, git, session, heroku

I'm using PHP to make a Heroku FB app, and whenever I do a git push, my users' sessions are destroyed. Why exactly does this happen? More importantly, how can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3):

Another option not mentioned is to use Memcached to store sessions. You can use the heroku addon Memcachier (https://addons.heroku.com/memcachier).

To configure php to use the memcached session handler, take a look at the extension's manual at http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php. Basically you set the php.ini directives:

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "localhost:11211"
```

Replace the save_path with the Memcachier address and port you are given when installing the add-on.

Comment: according to MemCachier's documentation (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcachier#php), memcached don’t support SASL authentication at this time and can’t be used with MemCachier.

Comment: @Owen you are correct that php-memcached does not support SASL for sessions (it does support it on the usual client since version 2.0, take a look at https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/blob/master/php_memcached.c#L2405).
I have opened an issue requestin support for SASL on session handler as well. https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/issues/47

Comment: hopefully they will add SASL support for the session handler soon :) by the way I found this: https://addons.heroku.com/memcache but as it is Christmas I have no time to figure out if it can be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to store your sessions in a database. You can store them in Postgres, or something like Redis. These will be persisted during deployments.

Comment: +1 for solution. I'll address the "why": Heroku apps use an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). When you push to Heroku, it takes what you've pushed and creates a "slug" - this slug is the source for spinning up instances of your app. When you push again, a new slug is made, and fresh instances are made. That is why you're losing the sessions - nothing generated server-side persists between deploys.

Answer (score 1):

I use AppFog, Memcachier now supports SASL, but I do not know how to continue.

```
session.save_handler = memcached

session.save_path = "localhost: 11211"
```

What is missing now is the authentication and I do not know how to put it
I found this but I do not know if it will work and how to use
http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.setsaslauthdata.php 
pd: I dont have access in appfog to php.ini so I need do this via htaccess, can you give me an example how to do this in htaccess ? 
https://docs.appfog.com/languages/php#php_ini 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to store your session data in your database. The plus side is you don't need to pay for another addon on Heroku in the event the free memcache plans don't do it for you.

Here is a great tutorial showing how to accomplish this (I am not affiliated with this tutorial in any way): https://culttt.com/2013/02/04/how-to-save-php-sessions-to-a-database